# Using Mac OS X CMake flags to hide build path in C/C++ library files

Tags: c++, c, macos, cmake, symbols

I was wondering if there was a way to strip away build paths from OS X library files.

eg.
I built [ceres-solver](https://github.com/ceres-solver/ceres-solver/) with CMake and conda, resulting in libceres.a.
I can see a few build paths in this file by running:

> $ strings libceres.a | grep "/Users/"
>   ...
>   /Users/abc/Anaconda3/conda-bld/work/src/logging.cc
>   ...

I have tried these flags in both CFLAGS and CXXFLAGS with no success:
-DNDEBUG -DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden

Any ideas?

Comment: strip the executables?

Comment: @RichardHodges Which executables? Does doing so affect the resulting lib--.a?

Comment: If you're concerned about the part that shows things above the root of the project folder, have you tried using the [`-fxxx-prefix-map`](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html) options? Also see [conan's article on deterministic builds](https://blog.conan.io/2019/09/02/Deterministic-builds-with-C-C++.html#build-folder-information-propagated-to-binaries) (it's mainly for GCC, but clang mirrors most of GCC's flags).